# How to open file from byteArray

Tags: java, arrays, performance, file

The below code can open a file using it's own software

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class JavaOpenFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //text file, should be opening in default text editor
        File file = new File("/Users/pankaj/source.txt");

        //first check if Desktop is supported by Platform or not
        if(!Desktop.isDesktopSupported()){
            System.out.println("Desktop is not supported");
            return;
        }

        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        if(file.exists()) desktop.open(file);

        //let's try to open PDF file
        file = new File("/Users/pankaj/java.pdf");
        if(file.exists()) desktop.open(file);
    }

}
```

Since software read bytes from a file, how can I make the above code to read from a byte array instead of a file located on disk? I don't want to convert the byte array to file before opening it.

Comment: `desktop.open` opens the file in an external application. To do that you really need a file on disk. Depending on the application, you may be able to write your data to a pipe instead (and open the application using ProcessBuilder). But direct access to in-process memory is not possible.

Comment: @Thilo Thanks for the recommendation, how would I able to do that; I am new to Java. When you say to writ my data to pipe, does that mean I have to write all the data to pipe? If yes, wouldn't that be heavy on the memory if I am to read a large file?